# App not working on AVD, only actual devices

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I'm trying to test my app, but having no luck with any emulators. I've tried a few different AVD's and BlueStacks. Due to the way they mount a virtual SDCard, my app is not finding a cache directory as expected. However, when I run the same app on two different Android phones, it seems to work properly. Facing this problem made me think there must be a better way of referencing the folder I'm looking for.

I'm using this in my onCreate:

```
    // Check if application exists
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).packageName.equals("com.someapphere")) {
            v.setText("Application Found");
            break;
        } else {
            v.setText("Application Not Found");
        }
    }

    if (v.getText() == "Application Found") {
        // Check for Cache Usage
        final File dataStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        try {
            File tCache = new File(dataStore.getAbsolutePath()
                 + "/Android/data/com.someapphere/cache");
            long tCacheSize = folderSize(tCache);

            if (tCacheSize == 0) {
                 v2.setText(" Nothing to do");
            } else {
              // Start Async task - delete files
              ...
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
              v2.setText(" Cache not found");
        }
    }
```

I took out some of the other irrelevant stuff I'm doing here, but the rest should replicate the issue. If it's not already obvious, I'm still quite new to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text can't be compared as '=='.

You should try like this:

```
v.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Application Found");
```

and its not working in emulator may be because you don't have SD card support in emulator.

In Eclipse go in menu **Window – Android SDK and Avg Manager**
Select **Virtual devices**
Select **AVD Name** where you need install SD card
Click on **Edit** button
In open dialog go to **SD card – Size**: and write 500
Press button **Edit AVD**
Run AVD emulator

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: Thanks for the tip about text comparison. However, all of my AVD configurations have SD space allocated already. One thing I have not yet tried, is installing a file manager into the AVD and verifying the structure is indeed /Android/data/com.app/cache. I'll do that next.

Comment: I'm getting a lint error after changing the text part. It's saying "The method equalsIgnoreCase(String) is undefined for the type CharSequence."

Comment: getText() returns charSequence. so we need to convert it to string like edited code.

Comment: I just pushed astro file manager into the AVD, and the folder is definitely missing. But in doing so, I see the /Android/data/ part is at least correct. Need to track down why the app I'm trying to clear hasn't put any cache there yet. I guess my real question is, will /Android/data/ be the same on all Android devices?

Comment: if you have created folder in external storage then you can get it as per your code. so you need to check whether you are creating folder in External storage or not??

Comment: Just to clarify, the cache folder I'm targeting is created by a different app (not mine). My app simply checks for it, and deletes it if found. My concern is, it might not find that folder on all devices if I'm specifically referencing the location.

Answer (score 0):

One possible bug:

```
v.getText() == "Application Found" // try .equals instead
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this code :

```
File tCache = new File(dataStore.getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/data/com.someapphere/cache");
```

With this code :

```
File cache_Folder = new File(dataStore + "/Android/data/com.someapphere/cache");
if (!cache_Folder.exists())
    cache_Folder.mkdirs();

File tCache = new File(dataStore + "/Android/data/com.someapphere/cache");
```

Comment: Since the whole idea of my app is to delete cache, I can't think of any reason I'd want to create the directory if it does not exist. One difference remaining would be the getAbsolutePath... in my existing structure, is this not necessary?

Comment: Then you need to use this : File cacheDir = new File(context.getCacheDir());

Comment: Correct me if I'm mistaken, but doesn't getCacheDir only apply for my own app? Rather, it won't make a difference for targeting the cache directory of a separate 3rd party app?

Comment: getCacheDir gets your own app cache dir, which is in the phone memory like : data/data/com.someapphere/cache.

Comment: I'm only interested in files on an sdcard, so that doesn't help any.